# MySQL instance lost when upgrading to Windows 10

Tags: windows, mysql, windows-10, windows-10-upgrade, mysql5

I had a running instance of MySQL 5.6 in my Windows 8.1. After upgrading to Windows 10, such instance is gone, including the Windows service for it.

Server data files are however intact. What would be the best way to recover or re-create the exact same instance (or the most similar) back in Windows 10?

Comment: Shame on you for putting `windows-10-upgrade` tag in this question. Those two phrases put together have no place in the Universe. ;-)  ( It's more like window-10-damage-control )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can manually put the service back as follows:

STEP 01) Open the Windows CLI as Administrator

STEP 02) `cd C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL 5.6\bin` or wherever `mysqld.exe` resides

STEP 03) Reinstall the service

```
mysqld --install
```

That's it.

I have mentioned this before in [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/233498/installing-isolated-instance-of-mysql-on-windows-using-silent-install-with-msi/234125#234125) and [DBA StackExchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/85984/how-to-get-mysql-automatically-running-when-i-start-tomcat-apache-on-windows/85986#85986)

**GIVE IT A TRY !!!**

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is reconfigure your current server. A nice step by step tutorial including screenshots can be found **[here](http://ivanrf.com/en/mysql-server-and-windows-10/)**, you do like this:

- First, open the application MySQL Installer – Community and click on Reconfigure
- Setup TCP/IP Port Number and Firewall
- Check Configure MySQL Server as a Windows Service and also check Start the MySQL Server at System Startup
- Apply the server configuration and your done!

Comment: I used this method to fix the same problem that Jago had, but it was not able to execute the last step of the Reconfigure... it couldn't start the service. I found it was loading a fresh default my.ini each time I ran it. I had a different MySQL data directory though (datadir in my.ini). Even if I adjusted the datadir in the my.ini as the reconfigure was running it wouldn't take. But I found all I had to do was cancel the MySQL reconfigure, make sure the datadir was correct in my.ini, go into Windows Services and start the new MySQL service there. That worked. What a headache though.

Answer (score 0):

Good advise. Don't forget to link to the correct ini file (if you have changed it)!

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/windows-start-service.html

Comment: Welcome to Super User. External links can break or be unavailable, in which case your answer would not be useful.  Please include the essential information within your answer and use the link for attribution and further reading.  Thanks.